# cmake bind custom command to a existed top level target fails

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I want to have one top level custom target, and nested submodules which are able to extend this already existed target by adding/binding custom_command to it. For now I face a problem: if `add_custom_command(TARGET target_name ...)` is used not in a file where the target is defined (target is defined on top level CMakeLists.txt), then this custom_command is simply ignored.

**Details:**

1) custom_target created on the top-level *CMakelists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_custom_target(custom_tg
COMMAND ls > custom_target.txt
)

add_custom_command(TARGET custom_tg
COMMAND ls > custom_command1.txt
)

add_subdirectory(sub)
```

2) In subdirectory "sub" there is other *CMakeLists.txt* (module) which I was hoping is able to extend the existed target with custom command.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET custom_tg
COMMAND ls > custom_command2.txt 
)
```

3) When I create build directory and run

```
cmake .. && make custom_tg
```

the output files are *custom_target.txt* and *custom_command1.txt*, but there is no *custom_command2.txt*, and that's actually my problem is.

If I look into *build/CMakeFiles/custom_tg.dir/build.make* I see no mention about *custom_command2.txt* there. Here is content of *build.make* file: http://pastebin.com/zVVS4sYL.

Actually I can't find any mention about *custom_command2.txt* in tree of files generated by Cmake, and this looks weird to me.

Looking forward for you help.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually solved by constructing dependencies between targets. For each command in one of your subdirs you would first add the 'local' command/target and then make it a dependency for the top-level one. Thereby forcing cmake to execute all 'local' targets before it executes the top-level one.

Comment: sorry, sure it's accepted, i tried to rate it, but i got message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: That's upvoting. Have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work